# What are all the martial arts styles seen in the Ip Man movies?

Tags: martial-arts, ip-man, ip-man-3

I know the ***Ip Man*** series has 3 parts, and in each film there are different types of martial arts shown.

One of them that name I remember is ***Wing chun***.

Can someone help me and name all the types of Martial Arts used in the ***Ip Man*** films?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Ip man 1:**

Fan Zi quan

A lesser known style that uses a barrage of attacks to Attack an opponent.

Choi lei fut

A very broad system of martial arts that encompasses all sorts of weapons and empty hand combat

**Ip man 2:**

[Xing yi quan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xing_Yi_Quan)

A direct, straight line internal martial art that focuses on explosive power. Looks stupid but very effective. Xingyi school won the last combined Chinese martial arts meet in 1930s which stopped prematurely cos there were too many injuries and they were the fiercest.

[Ba gua zhang](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baguazhang)

A system based on stepping and attacking according to 8 trigrams positions.  Very good at attacking from unexpected angles like Silat, one of the 3 main internal arts of China. Practitioners sometimes study it with Xing yi together as there is a Long history of collaboration between the 2 schools

[Hung gar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hung_Ga)

One of the most popular hard martial arts systems in the world. Hung gar pride themselves on their rock solid stances, ability to take a hit, and their heavy strikes. Most famous practitioner is Wong Fei Hong

Comment: I think there are more. anyway 1+

Answer (score 3):

The non-kung-fu-style martial arts used were:

- *Ip Man 1*: Karate (Style: Shotokan)
  This style of karate is Okinawa and was used by the Japanese military.
- *Ip Man 3*: Muay Thai. Originated in Thailand and involves more of knees and elbow moves you wouldn’t commonly practice in other martial arts.
- Other: Western Boxing, used in *Ip Man* 2 and 3 by Mike Tyson and The Twister. Boxing isn’t a martial art but a sport that involves two people with gloves fight each other using punches like jabs, crosses, and hooks.